# How to change the textview sequentially once the data inserted in database android

Tags: java, android, database, if-statement, android-sqlite

My requirement is,

I have Trailer Number 1 and name of the movie. Now once I inserted the data in table, I need to change the text as Trailer Number 2, this goes till Trailer Number 5. Because only 5 datas to be inserted. Also I will check whether the Trailer Number 1 is already existing or not in table. If not existing, I insert in Table but if exist, I change the text as Trailer Number 2. This is the exact scenario it should work.

But in my case, when I inserted Trailer Number 1, it jumps to Trailer Number 5 instead of not displaying Trailer Number 2.

After button click

```
boolean isFirstTrailerNumberExist = myDb.isExist("Trailer Number 1");
            boolean isSecondTrailerNumberExist = myDb.isExist("Trailer Number 2");
            boolean isThirdTrailerNumberExist = myDb.isExist("Trailer Number 3");
            boolean isFourthTrailerNumberExist = myDb.isExist("Trailer Number 4");
            boolean isFifthTrailerNumberExist = myDb.isExist("Trailer Number 5");

 if(isFirstTrailerNumberExist) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Trailer Number 1 already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(trailerNumberName.getText().toString(),
                        trailerNumberCount.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted){

                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    trailerNumberName.setText("Trailer Number 2");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Insertion failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

if(isSecondTrailerNumberExist){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Trailer Number 2 already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(trailerNumberName.getText().toString(),
                        trailerNumberCount.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted){

                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    trailerNumberName.setText("Trailer Number 3");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Insertion failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
//the same repeats for third, fourth and fifth trailer too to check in db

if(isThirdTrailerNumberExist){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Trailer Number 3 already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(trailerNumberName.getText().toString(),
                        trailerNumberCount.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted){

                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    trailerNumberName.setText("Trailer Number 4");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Insertion failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            if(isFourthTrailerNumberExist){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Trailer Number 4 already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(trailerNumberName.getText().toString(),
                        trailerNumberCount.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted){

                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    trailerNumberName.setText("Trailer Number 5");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Insertion failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            if(isFifthTrailerNumberExist){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Trailer Number 5 already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(trailerNumberName.getText().toString(),
                        trailerNumberCount.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted){

                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    trailerNumberName.setText("Trailer Number 1");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TrailerNumberActivity.this,"Insertion failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
```

This is how I repeated to display till Trailer 5 but problem is after inserting Trailer 1, it jumps to Trailer 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it will jump on trailer no 5 because when you click the button initially all ---TrailerNumberExist will return false, so sequentially it will set text to  'Trailer Number 2', 'Trailer Number 3' and so on until it stops at 'Trailer Number 5'

do it like this

```
 if(!isFirstTrailerNumberExist) {
    // insert and show your entry here
    insertDataAndUpdateText("Trailer Number 2");
}else if(!isSecondTrailerNumberExist){
    // insert and show your entry here
    insertDataAndUpdateText("Trailer Number 3");
}else if(!isThirdTrailerNumberExist){
    // insert and show your entry here
    insertDataAndUpdateText("Trailer Number 4");
}
```

and so on..
Use the single method to make your code optimal

now it will enter sequentially on button click and show the output

Comment: Thanks. So instead of if, I need to check with else if(!)" right?

Comment: correct. and use debugger it will tell you exactly whats going on. you can learn it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90XDJTriJ1s